# How to change the form action in Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

Does anyone know how to change the form action in Contact Form 7? I want to generate leads using Contact Form 7 so if anyone knows, please help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WordPress API is mostly working based on Event Driven Programming therefore whatever changes can be done through either action or filter hook.

CF7 also provided lots of hooks and to modify URL you have to use `wpcf7_form_action_url`

```
function custom_action_url( $url ) {
    $wpcf7    = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $wpcf7_id = $wpcf7->id();

    if ( $wpcf7_id == YOUR_FORM_ID ) { // Replace YOUR_FORM_ID to desired CF7 form id.
        $url = 'send.php'; // replace this with the new action url (excluding the 'http://')
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_action_url', 'custom_action_url' );
```

Comment: Missed adding the filter  `add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_action_url', 'custom_action_url' );` also in 132 line string is not enclosed in quotes.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/11srz0n .. Added but it is still not working

Comment: Share the value in `$wpcf7_id` variable.

Comment: wpcf7-f21036-p21072-o2 this is the id in the form

Comment: `var_dump` or `print_r` the variable `$wpcf7` and share the same.

Comment: Sir i am web designer so i am new to it . will you please let me know what exactly you need from me

Comment: No problem. Add this `print_r(  $wpcf7 );` just above the if condition and share the output generated by this function. The output will be echoed in any page/post which using the CF7 form.

Comment: Check you're changing the url of correct CF7 form in front end by moving the `print_r(  $wpcf7 );` inside the if condition, therefore, the object should be displayed in that only form other forms are not affected by this.